# SQL query showing missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle

Query to pull the data between Yseterday 6AM to today 6AM ...

```
  SELECT 
  lot_id,
  log_time,
  batch_no,
  eqp_id,
  STATION_ID,
  EXTRACTVALUE (META_DATA, '/lot_info/A3') AS A3,
  EXTRACTVALUE (META_DATA, '/lot_info/A3Info') AS A3Info,
  EXTRACTVALUE (
    META_DATA,
    '/lot_info/apc_status_info'
  ) AS apc_status_info 
FROM
  t_dlis_log_history 
WHERE (
    (EQP_ID = 'ALC4360') 
    OR (EQP_ID = 'ALC4361') 
    OR (EQP_ID = 'ALC1360') 
    OR (EQP_ID = 'ALC1361') 
    OR (EQP_ID = 'ALC1362') 
    OR (EQP_ID = 'ALC1363') 
    OR (EQP_ID = 'ALC1364') 
    OR (EQP_ID = 'ALC1365') 
    OR (EQP_ID = 'ALC355') 
    OR (EQP_ID = 'ALC353') 
    OR (EQP_ID = 'ALC4350') 
    OR (EQP_ID = 'ALC354')
  ) 
  AND ((
    log_time >= DATEADD (
      HOUR,
      6,
      CONVERT(VARCHAR (10), GETDATE (), 110)
    ) 
    AND (
      log_time <= DATEADD (
        HOUR,
        6,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR (10), GETDATE () + 1, 110)
      )
    )
  )
```

It is showing error missing expression ...

Comment: Just a suggestion, instead of so many OR's you can use IN statement!

Comment: Oh k ... but when i am compiling this it is showing error message "Parser error '1071': Warning: SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression" ... any idea ?

Comment: Where in the Oracle manual did you find the `dateadd`, `convert` or `getdate()`  function?

Comment: Do ***NOT*** just remove the text of your question if you have an answer. That totally defeats the purpose of this site. Accept the answer that solved your problem so that others see that this issue is resolved.

Comment: If you are working with Oracle, you should tag the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing Oracle syntax with SQL Server syntax.

`EXTRACTVALUE` is an Oracle function, but `DATEADD` is a SQL Server function. According to the error message I guess you have Oracle.

In Oracle you can use this to add hours to a date (in this case you add 6 hours to yesterday 00:00 and today 00:00):

```
log_time >= trunc(sysdate-1) + 6/24 and log_time <= trunc(sysdate) + 6/24
```

Or:

```
log_time between trunc(sysdate-1) + 6/24 and trunc(sysdate) + 6/24
```

(Also, in your original query you were missing a `)` at the end)

Comment: You mean to say .. ((log_time >= (sysdate-1) + 6/24)
 AND (log_time <= sysdate + 6/24)) .. does it pull data between yesterday 6AM to Today ^AM ...

Comment: This qury is not working ... This query is pulling last 6 hours information .. but i need yesterday mng 6 to today mng 6 ... how to do that ...

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the date because everyday morning this script runs automatically ....when this script ran it should pull previous day 6am to present day 6am ... how we could achieve this

Comment: You are welcome. Since you are new, please don't forget to mark the question answered by checking the checkmark before the answer you liked most.